# the process of executing a command with '&&'

Tags: bash, shell, variables, ampersand

When executing `var=foo && echo $var` in bash

the result will be: `foo`

Does that mean  `$var` expands  after  `var=foo` is executed?
I want to understand the process.

Comment: `&&` is AND operator. IF left to `&&` is true or completed successfully then right to `&&` will be executed.

Comment: i did some grammar improvements

Answer (score 1):

See [bash manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html) which states:

> AND and OR lists are sequences of one or more pipelines separated by
>   the && and || control operators, respectively. **AND and OR lists are
>   executed with left associativity.**  An AND list has the form
>
> ```
>        command1 && command2
> ```
>
> command2 is executed if, and only if, command1 returns an exit status
>   of zero.

(emphasis mine)

That means `echo $var` will be executed only if the assignment operation (`var=foo`) was successful.

It's equivalent to:

```
var=foo   
if [[ $? -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo $var
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

The workings of bash are intimately related to the workings of the C programming language.

`&&` *is* short-circuited (as it is in C). And like C, the argument on the right hand side of `&&` is *not* evaluated until evaluation of the left hand side completes. (Formally in C we say that `&&` is a *sequence* point.)

So `echo $var` is *only* expanded once (i) `var=foo` is evaluated and (ii) if it evaluates to a value that coerces to 0 (which denotes success).

Comment: you mean value that coerces to 0 :) in bash, 0 is true, 1 (or more) is an error. Writting true/false would be clearer imo.

Comment: 0 is *success*, nonzero is *failure*. It causes more problems than it avoids to constantly try to think of them as boolean values.

Comment: @chepner: Thanks for that. I've forgotten and relearned that at least twice ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does. Generally, the following combination of two commands:

```
cmd1 && cmd2
```

implies that execute `cmd2` if the execution of `cmd1` is successful.